# Tinymce right click paste mouse enable

Tags: javascript, tinymce

(I disabled the contextmenu plugin.)
In tinymce i would like to paste a text with the right click menu mouse like in this text editor here.
I noticed that i can do that when the selector is blinking on the first line.
Where can i set up that ?

Regards

Frank

Answer (score 14):

For anyone else seeing this a few years later, here's what I did to enable right-click paste for my TinyMCE editor:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".TinyMceTextEditor",
    plugins: "contextmenu",
    contextmenu: "paste | link image inserttable | cell row column deletetable"
});
```

If you enable the contextmenu plugin, then you can specify the contextmenu itself and include "paste". This way you can bypass the default right-click context menu and still get the paste option (plus a lot of other functionality). The other options I have in the contextmenu are the defaults.

Comment: This had no effect for me until I also added `contextmenu_never_use_native: true`.

Comment: This doesn't work. Am using the new version of Tiny 5.5.1

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on version 5 :

Either disable the TinyMCE context menu and use the native browser context menu :

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#context-menu',
    contextmenu: false
});
```

Or enable copy and paste in TinyMCE :

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#context-menu',
    contextmenu: 'copy paste'
});
```

Comment: Browser native only works if you right click exactly in the content line - if the editor is higher it does not work. Copy Paste Plugin in context menu does not work in Firefox & Chrome as of now for security reasons.
Have not solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tinymce contextmenu plugin. We use a modified version of it as an own plugin to show different option to the user.

Comment: are you able to elaborate on your modified version? Thanks

Comment: are you using tinymce3 or tinymce4?